# VBA - Copy all of data in column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that searches for a specific column header name, finds the column, copies all the data below it, and pastes it under the exact same column header in ws2.

Worksheet1 has headers like; 
"First Name", "Last name", "ID"
With all the data underneath them.

Worksheet2 already has the same titles but not the data.

I've tried this, but I keep getting an subscript out of range run-time error:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks("WS1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("WS2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Copy

ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which line gives the error? Also, `Cells` should be fully qualified with a worksheet reference as well.

Comment: Not related to the error, but you stated that ws2 already has the titles (probably in row1), but you do the paste into row1, so your titles will get overwritten.

Comment: Line 5: Set ws1 gives me the error

Comment: There's no open workbook with that name, or if there is, it doesn't have a worksheet named "Sheet1"

Comment: Seems like a good idea to OPEN the xlsm before trying to refer to it.

Comment: It was always open when I ran the macro

Comment: You might not have both workbooks open in the same Application. Make sure you can see both in the VBA Editor. If you can't, try closing WS2 and opening it through WS1